# Racket - Remove a key from association list

Tags: racket

I'm trying to write a function which consumes a number, key, and an association list, al, and produces the association list resulting from removing key from al.
For example:

```
(check-expect (remove-al 5 (list (list 4 "A") (list 5 "B") (list 1 "C")))
              (list (list 4 "A") (list 1 "C")))
```

I'm not permitted to use certain functions, like map, filter or remove, but have managed to write this so far. Below is my code:

```
define (remove-al key al)
  (cond
    [(empty? al) empty]
    [(= key (first (first al))) empty]
    [else (cons (first al)
                (remove-al key (rest al)))]))
```

Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: What should `(remove-al 1 (list (list 1 10) (list 2 20)))` be? What does yours return?

Comment: It returns empty...

Comment: So what should be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept behind this algorithm is to think of it in terms of an extended append implementation. If you are to look up the implementation of append in Racket, it is a recursive algorithm where the base case checks if the rhs list is empty, but if not it cons the first value of the lhs list with the result of the recursive call with the rest of lhs list and rhs. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29137191/9238288) is a link to the implementation. The algorithm is simply the append implementation with an extra check to make sure to ignore the cons recursive call if the first element of the list matches the key.

**SPOILERS**

---->

```
(define (remove-al key lhs rhs)
  (cond [(empty? lhs) rhs]
        [else (cond [(not (=(first (first lhs)) key))
                     (cons (first lhs) (remove-al key (rest lhs) rhs))]
                    [else (remove-al key (rest lhs) rhs)])]))

(check-expect (remove-al 5 (list (list 4 "A") (list 5 "B") (list 1 "C")) '() )
              (list (list 4 "A") (list 1 "C")))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use append and if...But thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Sillage No problem, but I have modifed the code, and now it doesn't use append or if and works in BSL.